# While loop doesn't seem to finish after EOF

Tags: c, while-loop, eof

I am trying to write a while-loop that terminates at the end of file. I have used 
`while(!feof(stdin))` in the code bellow, but the loop doesn't seem to terminate even if EOF is reached (I am reading from file). When executed in terminal, the program does all that is supposed to, but then keeps going for several seconds before "program.exe stopped working" window opens.
I have googled for almost several hours, tried different versions (variations for `while (1)` followed by `int check = scanf("%d", &from); if (check == EOF) break;`) and nothing worked for me.

The possibly problematic part of code:

```
while(!feof(stdin))
{
    check2 = scanf(" %d %d", &from, &to);
// some input checks with check2
    lcm1 = useky[from];

    if (from != (to-1))  
    {
        for (i = (from+1); i < to; i++) 
        {
            lcm2 = useky[i];
            lcm_temp = lcm_vypocet(lcm1,lcm2);
            lcm1 = lcm_temp;
        }       
    }
    printf("Vozidel: %lld\n", lcm1);
}
```

The entire code:

```
long long int lcm_vypocet(long long int x, long long int y) {
long long int a, b, t, gcd, lcm;

a = x;
b = y;

while (a != 0) {
t = a;
a = b % a;
b = t;
}

gcd = b;
lcm = x*(y/gcd);

return lcm;
}    

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

int i=0, check, check1=0, check2, highestIndex, from, to;    
int *useky, *useky_copy, *temp;
long long int lcm1, lcm2, lcm_temp;
char delimiter, check0;

printf("Pocty pruhu:\n");
useky = (int*) malloc(sizeof(*useky));
useky_copy = useky;

scanf("%1s", &check0);
if (check0!='{') 
{
    printf("Nespravny vstup.\n");
    exit(0);
}

for (i=0;;i++) 
{
    check = scanf(" %d %1s", &useky[i], &delimiter);
    highestIndex = i;

    if (check1==2) // break from the loop on end of input 
    {
        break;  
    }
    temp = (int*)realloc (useky, sizeof(*useky) + sizeof(int)); 
    if ( temp == NULL ) 
    {
        free(useky);
        printf("Nespravny vstup.\n");
        return 1;   
    }
    useky = temp;
}
printf("Trasy:\n");

while(!feof(stdin))
{
    check2 = scanf(" %d %d", &from, &to);
    lcm1 = useky[from];

    if (from != (to-1))  
    {
        for (i = (from+1); i < to; i++) 
        {
            lcm2 = useky[i];
            lcm_temp = lcm_vypocet(lcm1,lcm2);
            lcm1 = lcm_temp;
        }       
    }
    // lcm1 je výsledný počet vozidel.
    printf("Vozidel: %lld\n", lcm1);
}

free(useky_copy);   

return 0;
}
```

Does anyone have any tip for what might be wrong? I will really appreciate any help!

Comment: `while(!feof())` is **always a bug** because EOF is only detected **after** I/O, not before. Maybe read the comp.lang.c FAQ? http://c-faq.com/stdio/feof.html

Comment: Please read [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: Any tip? It sounds trite, but to read the man page for functions you are new to.

Comment: Point of detail `if (check1==2)` will never be true, since `int check1=0` is only set when defined. It's good to see you using the return value from `scanf` but it is a bit hit and miss.

Comment: Test your actual i/o operations for errors, not after the fact. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20034876/c-read-scanf-until-feofstdin-dont-output-error

Comment: `check = scanf(" %d %1s", &useky[i], &delimiter);
    ....

    if (check1==2)` --> Certainly code should be assigning and checking the same variable here.

Comment: `char check0; ...scanf("%1s", &check0);` is bad code as `scanf("%1s"...` will attempt to save a character and a null character into insufficient memory.

Comment: `check2 = scanf(" %d %d", &from, &to);
// some input checks with check2` --> Do not use `from` unless `check2 >= 1`. Do not use `to` unless `check2 >= 2`.

Comment: Thank you everyone. I know the code is still not very nice, but I managed to get rid of the bug (`while (fscanf(stdin," %d %d", &from, &to) != EOF)`).

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code: indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.   2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line.  3) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: (malloc, calloc, realloc) 1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: when the parameters for `main()` are not going to be used, then use the signature: `int main( void )`.  When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum, use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  It is missing the needed `#include` statements for the needed header files.  (do you expect us to guess as to which (if any) header files the posted code is actually including?)

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: insert appropriate horizontal spacing: inside parens, after commas, after semicolons, around C operators.

Comment: regarding: `while(!feof(stdin))` never works.  suggest replacing `while(!feof(stdin))
    {
        check2 = scanf(" %d %d", &from, &to);`  with: `while( 2 == scanf(" %d %d", &from, &to) )`

Comment: when outputting an error message, it should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`  via something similar to: `fprintf( stderr, "...\n", ... )`  However, when the error is from a system function, the text indicating why the system thinks the error occurred should also be output.  Suggest using: `perror()` as that outputs to `stderr` and includes the text related to the `errno` value

Comment: regarding: `if (check1==2)`  Nothing has updated the value in `check1` so the value will depend on what ever trash was on the stack where the variable is located.  Perhaps you meant: `if (check==2)`  however, that means the prior call to `scanf()` was successful,  NOT that the end of file was reached.

Comment: it is considered poor programming practice to have several (especially unrelated) variables those names only differ by some digit value

Comment: it is best practice to limit the 'scope' of variables to where they are used rather than declaring all the variables at the beginning of a function.

Comment: regarding: `lcm = x*(y/gcd);` these are all integer values, so the math will be integer math.  In the current scenario, the result will usually be 0.  Probably not what you want.